# Updating flutter app data from REST API in real-time

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using Flutter for the app and Django with Postgres for my backend APIs. I want to update the data from API in-app to update in real-time, what is the best way to do it. I went through a lot of blog posts and SO answers and have got the following solutions, Any better solutions would be appreciated

1. Websockets - difficult to scale
2. Refresh APIs after every n seconds - Difficult to scale
3. Firestore in build functions but I don't want to migrate to firebase.

Are there any better solutions? I want the solution to scale to many users so please let me know the best solution for this. Thanks

Update:
I have two data sources, one is the flutter app itself and another is a web dashboard, I want the data in the app which is a listview to get updated whenever new data is added from the dashboard in real-time. The data in the app is a listview that should be updated in real time with new records from the API.

Comment: Technically, in order to update data in real-time  you need a real-time databse( which is not the case for you), but don't worry always their is a work around , could you please include more details about your problem ( which type of data, is their a display condition, is it updated from client side , Flutter, ... ?

Comment: @Hajed.Kh Sorry for the delay, I have updated the kind of data, Please let me know if any further explanation is required. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if this is good solution, but you can try to use FCM from Firebase (you wrote only about firestore/real-time database).

Every time app is in reasumed state it can register token in your backend, and every time web dashboard is being changed, server can send push notification to the app with data/trigger to fetch data.

WebDashboard -> Backend -> FCM(with trigger/ full data) -> Mobile